# How to create and reference custom heading ids with reStructuredText?

Tags: restructuredtext

Currently, if I have:

```
My header
=========

`My header`_
```

`rst2html` Docutils 0.14 produces:

```
<div class="document" id="my-header">
<h1 class="title">My header</h1>

<p><a class="reference internal" href="#my-header">My header</a></p>
```

Is it possible to obtain the following ouptut instead:

```
<h1 class="title" id="my-custom-header">My header</h1>

<p><a class="reference internal" href="#my-custom-header">My header</a></p>
```

So note how I want two changes:

- the id to be inside the heading, not on a separate div
- control over the actual id

The closest I could get was:

```
<div class="document" id="my-header">
<span id="my-custom-header"></span>
<h1 class="title">My header</h1>

<p><a class="reference external" href="my-custom-header">My header</a></p>
```

but this is still not ideal, as I now have multiple ids floating around, and not inside the `h1`.

Asciidoc for example has that covered with:

```
[[my-custom-header]]
== My header

<<my-custom-header>>
```

Comment: I think this is the closest you can get. Since you can have more than one custom link to the same title, rst2html won't insert the first as the id and the second as a span anchor. Both will be span anchors. And I think this is ok as it works the same as the way you want.